# Pyglets Window.on_key_press and Window.on_key_release affected by key repeat on ubuntu 12.10 with unity

Tags: ubuntu, pyglet, ubuntu-unity

On [pyglet's documentation](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/keyboard_events.html) it is stated that

```
The Window.on_key_press and Window.on_key_release events are fired when
any key on the keyboard is pressed or released, respectively. These events 
are not affected by "key repeat" -- once a key is pressed there are no more
events for that key until it is released.
```

However when the  Unity's keyboard setting called "Key presses repeat when key is held down" is selected, pyglet (1.2alpha1) will repeat on_key_press and on_key_release when a key remains pressed.

This unintended behavior can be tested by the following script a toggling the setting:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    print "key press"

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    print "key release"

pyglet.app.run()
```

Is there a way to override key repeat for a single window? Any other workaround is also welcome.

This setting is on by default and it is not pleasant for a game to request setting it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround would be something like:

```
pressed_keys = []

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol in pressed_keys:
        return
    # handle pressed key
    pressed_keys.append(symbol)

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol in pressed_keys:
        pressed_keys.remove(symbol)
```